# Webform, let data expire after a period of time

Tags: 7, webforms

How might I expire data collected in Webform? That is, I'd like to purge data after a period of 6 to 18 months.

Alternatively, I'd be happy to find a module that cleans up old data in a Drupal 7 database.

Comment: Try the sandbox project [Webform auto-delete](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/rolodmonkey/2172727).

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Well. I tested that sandbox project in a vm install and it worked. Go ahead and put that in the answer below. While not released, this is the best mechanism at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Webform auto-delete](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/rolodmonkey/2172727)  sandbox project.

> Automatically delete webform submissions after a set period of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Webform Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_scheduler) module

also.

> It adds an optional start date and end date field to the webform form settings. If the current date and time falls outside the specified window, the webform is disabled.

or create a rule with [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules)